# Why does inserting sequential elements in a tree require more time than inserting random elements into a tree?

Tags: c++, tree, time-complexity

*This is not homework* I'm taking a data structures class and we recently finished trees. At the end of class, my professor showed this image.
[image: Tree Times]

ConcreteBTree is a binary tree that doesnt self balance. I have a few questions about the times it took to complete these procedures.

1. Why does it take so much more time to insert 100,000 sequential elements into ConcreteBTree than it takes to insert random elements into it? My intuition would be that since elements are sequential, it should take less time than it takes to insert 1,000,000 random elements.
2. Why are the times of insert() and find() of ConcreteBTree with random elements so close together? Is it because both have the same time complexity? I thought insert was O(1) and find was O(n)

I'd really like to understand what is going on here, any explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Inserting sequential items into a non-balancing tree is just about the worst thing you can do. You will essentially end up creating a linked-list, since you will always end up using either only the left node or only the right node.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inserting sequential items( 1,2,3,4...) to a binary tree will cause it to always add the nodes to the same side( left for example ) . 
When you insert random items you will add nodes randomly left and right.

Adding sequentially will cause the list to behave as a ordinary linked list ( for the sequential items) because new items will have to visit every previously added item and that will take O(n) steps , when adding randomly it will take O( log N) steps on average.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So does that imply that for randomly inserted elements, since they are random there is a good chance of the tree becoming balanced because the probability of the random node being larger or smaller than it's parent is .5?

Comment: since they are random there is a good chance of the tree becoming balanced, Yes, until you start removing and adding new items.

Comment: Got it, could you look at the image and see if ConcreteBTree's find()'s match up? I dont see how you can find 1 million random elements much faster you find 100,000 random elements

Comment: @MauriceAbney 100.000 elements aren't random. They were added sequentially. They were only searched randomly. 1 million elements were added randomly and are randomly searched for much faster.

Answer (score 3):

Armin's answered Q1.

> 2.Why are the times of insert() and find() of ConcreteBTree with random elements so close together? Is it because both have the same time complexity? I thought insert was O(1) and find was O(n)

`insert` and `find` have to do the same work - they go down through whatever weird tree you've put together looking for that last node under which the value either is linked or would be (and will be in the case of `insert`), so they do the same number of comparisons and node traversals, taking similar time.

Insertion of random elements in a balanced tree is O(log<sub>2</sub>N).  Your insertions of random values into an tree that doesn't self-rebalance will be a bit but not dramatically worse as some branches will end up considerably longer than others - you'll probably get some kind of bell curve of branch lengths.  `insert`'s only O(1) if you already know the node in the tree under which the insert is to be done (i.e. that find step above is normally needed).  `find`'s only O(n) if every node in the tree has to be visited, which is only the case for a pathologically unbalanced tree, effectively forming a linked list, as you've already been told you can generate by inserting pre-sorted elements.